# Secure erase trashed files in El Capitan

Tags: macos, trash, secure-erase

I accidentally emptied my trash (not secure emptied it) but there were some files in there that I should've properly erased. Is there a way I can bring them back to properly erase them?

Comment: You can erase empty space left on your disk in Disk Utility. It takes several times depend on your free disk space. I think there is no way to bring those files back to the Trash. If you had installed DiskDrill you can use it to undo empty trash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a tool like https://www.prosofteng.com/datarescue-mac-data-recovery/ which has some free tiers to recover limited files.

If your Mac OS supports the FileVault full disk encryption, doing that would be far better and let you never worry about secure erase since everything is cryptographically erased without your password. If that's not an option, use Disk Utility and securely wipe all free space on the drive one time.

I'm assuming you don't have an SSD which don't support secure erase - in that case, see here.

- [Secure delete an erased file using same file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/159247/secure-delete-an-erased-file-using-same-file)